# dataGridView impedir reubicacion al actualizarlo

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Mi programa contiene un `dataGridView` donde se muestran una serie de datos, este se actualizar cada X segundos con un `Timer_tick`, el problema es que en cada actualización la fila seleccionada del `DataGridView` vuelve a ser la primera, el objetivo sería si estoy a mitad de tabla, no me suba hasta arriba del todo perdiendo así la visualización del dato que me interesa.

**Método de selección;**

```
    private void DataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e
    {

        try
        {
            id = Int32.Parse(dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["id_curso"].Value.ToString());
            row = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Index;

            datos[0] = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["titulo"].Value.ToString();//todos los datos del dataGrid y mostrar los datos en los txt correspondientes
            datos[1] = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["cod_curso"].Value.ToString();
            datos[2] = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["descripcion"].Value.ToString();
            datos[3] = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["horas"].Value.ToString();
            datos[4] = dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells["id_curso"].Value.ToString();
            txtTitulo.Text = datos[0];
            txtCodcurso.Text = datos[1];
            txtDescripcion.Text = datos[2];
            txtHoras.Text = datos[3];
        }
        catch (System.NullReferenceException) {

            MessageBox.Show("Los datos de este curso estan corruptos y no se pueden visualizar"); }
    }
```

**Evento Timer_tick:**

```
    public override async void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("DataGridView actualizado");
        var list = await Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            return await _api.ObtenerCursos(string.Empty);
        });
        dataGridView1.DataSource = list;
        dataGridView1.ClearSelection();

        try
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Selected = true;
            //dataGridView1.Rows[row].Selected = true;
        }
        catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }

    }
```

Comment: Añade el código que hayas probado para poder ayudarte mejor y para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por la comunidad.

Comment: Así a primeras, te puedo decir que puedes añadir una variable que vaya guardando el índice de la fila que tienes seleccionada cada vez que se selecciona una fila diferente o justo antes de actualizar (aprovechando el timer) entonces despues de realizar el actualizado seleccionar la row que ya tenias seleccionada antes.

Comment: Lo que has comentado esta hecho, el problema es que en cada actualización sigue regresando a la parte superior del DataGridView, aunque se mantenga la fila seleccionada.

Comment: El código debes añadirlo como texto y no como foto, así podemos copiarlo y pegarlo para poder hacer pruebas.

Comment: Listo, ya lo añadí como texto gracias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Una vez tienes seleccionada la fila que tenias seleccionada antes de actualizar, debes poner la instrucción [`FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.firstdisplayedscrollingrowindex(v=vs.110).aspx) para que la `DataGridView` haga scroll hasta el índice que le indicas (que es la row que había seleccionada), de la siguiente forma:

```
    try
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows[row].Cells[0].Selected = true;
        //dataGridView1.Rows[row].Selected = true;
        dataGridView1.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = row;
    }
    catch (System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException) { }
```

Comment: Gracias, tu solución funcionó :)